# What mode is vim in when I press a single 'r' and is it possible to have a mapping here?

Tags: vim

For a quick overview, I map `<s-space>` to `<esc>` so I can more easily cancel out of things without moving my hand to the escape key. For example, when I want out of insert mode, or to cancel something.

`inoremap <esc> <nop>  " to force me to stop using <esc>

cnoremap <esc> <nop>

nnoremap <s-space> <nop>

onoremap <s-space> <esc>

inoremap <s-space> <esc>`

However, if I press 'r' vim is waiting for a character, and when I press `<s-space>`,  I end up replacing with a space, instead of canceling the replace operation.  Is it possible for mappings to work after pressing 'r' once, while waiting for a character?

Thanks!

Comment: No it's not possible and it would make no sense at all. `rx` replaces the character under the cursor with `x` why would you want a mapping there?

Comment: It's worth noting that the `inoremap` version should work in full replace mode initiated with a capital `R`. It's just the one-character replacement with `r` that you can't map a replacement for.

Comment: @romainl  For consistency, I wanted to use the same mapping for "cancel" regardless of what I am doing in vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find you've accidentally pressed <kbd>r</kbd>, how about just tapping <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>?

This will make the replacement but immediately undo it again, without you having to move your hands from the letter keys.

Comment: I think presning `u` once should be enough. Afaik that already undoes the last actian, which was the replace. At least in my vim this seems to work this way.

Comment: The first u supplies the replacement (i.e. the character is replaced with the letter u) and the second u does the undo so you're back where you started.

Comment: I have misunderstood the scenario. I thought the replacement to `r` had already been supplied and then only one `u` would be needed.